# Theming outlined mat-input box, mat-select and mat-paginator

Tags: angular, angular-material-5, angular-material-6

I am trying to theme the above mentioned elements. However, if I apply the styles at a global scope, it just does not theme every aspect of the element.

Here is the approach that I have implemented/tried.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b8a8oa

Would appreciate any pointers on this. I have never styled complex angular components before. I am here to learn. The documentation on theming the various components at material.angular.io does not have much information. Hence, I asked here.

Thank you

Comment: is it not enough setting a border?
 <div [ngStyle]="{'border':'1px solid red'}">
    <mat-label >Outline form field</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder" style="color: white">
    <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are new `css` as well :) You added `inline style` and expecting all the `element` will be impacted.

If you are targeting multiple `elements` then you must use the `css class` to achieve this.

Since you are using angular material, let me tell you it has its own set of `css class` that needs to be overwrite by using following syntax

```
/deep/ {className}{

}
```

ex

```
/deep/ .mat-dialog-container{
     background-color: cyan;
}
```

For demo you can use link - 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b8a8oa-udwwjz

Comment: Stackblitz link is invalid

Comment: Also, I want to understand how to style them individually before I can devise a global scope strategy, hence the inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

I'm investigation how to do this also with other components. that way that you are trying, override the CSS I did it and It's works. But it's not the correct one and It's a lot of recurrent overriding work all the time for each new component. The correct way to do this is create a custom theme for material design. Here is the doc that I'm following so far:

https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components

This is my recommendation, follow this path.